# How to check and correct the invalid HTML from the array elements in following scenario?

Tags: php, html, arrays, dom, xml-parsing

I've an array titled `$comments` as follows :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [text] => Second Comment Added                
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [text] => This is the long comment added to check thwe size of the comment on the device,if the size is more then add the hyperlink button to go on to the next page
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [text] => This comment is of two lines need to check more about it                
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [text] => This comment is of two lines need to check more                
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [text] => Uploading Photo  for comment <div title="comment_attach_image">

<a title="" title="colorbox" href="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/CnYTVQdATAOQTkMxpAq4" ><img src="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/CnYTVQdATAOQTkMxpAq4" height="150px" width="150px" /></a>

<a href="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/CnYTVQdATAOQTkMxpAq4" class="comment_attach_image_link_dwl">Download</a>

</div>                
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [text] => test                
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [text] => Amit&#039;s pic<div class="comment_attach_image">
            <a class="group1 cboxElement" href="http://52.1.47.143/file/attachment/2015/03/e55f0f3080eb9828270a7963648a5826.jpeg" ><img src="http://52.1.47.143/file/attachment/2015/03/e55f0f3080eb9828270a7963648a5826.jpeg" height="150px" width="150px" /></a>

            <a class="comment_attach_image_link_dwl"  href="http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_e55f0f3080eb9828270a7963648a5826.jpeg" >Download</a>
            </div>
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [text] => PDF file added<div class="comment_attach_file">
            <a class="comment_attach_file_link" href="http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_1b87d4420c693f2bbdf738cbf2457d89.pdf" >1b87d4420c693f2bbdf738cbf2457d89.pdf</a>

            <a class="comment_attach_file_link_dwl"  href="http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_1b87d4420c693f2bbdf738cbf2457d89.pdf" >Download</a>
            </div>                
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [text] => Just did it...                
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [text] => Akki <div title="comment_attach_image">

<a title="" title="colorbox" href="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/NJqijbKTIOA0ZJBNknsm" ><img src="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/NJqijbKTIOA0ZJBNknsm" height="150px" width="150px" /></a>

<a href="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/NJqijbKTIOA0ZJBNknsm" class="comment_attach_image_link_dwl">Download</a>

</div>                
        )

)
```

In this array two elements contain invalid HTML. `$comments[4] and $comments[9]` contain invalid HTML because of this I'm not able to parse it in XML.

I want these two elements after clean up as follows(other elements should remain same). All the array keys should be intact :

```
Array
    (
[4] => Array
            (
                [text] => Uploading Photo  for comment <div class="comment_attach_image">

    <a title="colorbox" href="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/CnYTVQdATAOQTkMxpAq4" ><img src="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/CnYTVQdATAOQTkMxpAq4" height="150px" width="150px" /></a>

    <a href="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/CnYTVQdATAOQTkMxpAq4" class="comment_attach_image_link_dwl">Download</a>

    </div>                
            )  
[9] => Array
            (
                [text] => Akki <div class="comment_attach_image">

    <a title="colorbox" href="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/NJqijbKTIOA0ZJBNknsm" ><img src="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/NJqijbKTIOA0ZJBNknsm" height="150px" width="150px" /></a>

    <a href="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/NJqijbKTIOA0ZJBNknsm" class="comment_attach_image_link_dwl">Download</a>

    </div>                
            )

    )
```

If you notice closely the `<div title="comment_attach_image">` has been changed to `<div class="comment_attach_image">` and the extra `title` attribute containing blank value has been removed.

How to check this invalid HTML and get it correct in PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Following is my parsing code :

```
foreach($comments as $key=>$comment) {
    $text = strstr($comment['text'], '<div');
    if (strlen($text) <= 0) {
      $comments[$key]['type_id'] =  'text';
      $comments[$key]['url'] =  '';
      $comments[$key]['text'] =  $comment['text'];
    } else if($xml = @simplexml_load_string($text)) { 
      $comments[$key]['type_id'] =  substr(strrchr($xml['class'], '_'), 1);
      $comments[$key]['url'] = str_replace(array('href=','"'), '',$xml->a['href']->asXML());
      $comments[$key]['text'] =  strtok($comment['text'], '<');           
    } else {
      continue;
    }    
  }
```

Comment: Hi, if i understood your question correctly, you want to change the `<div title="comment_attach_image">` to `<div class="comment_attach_image">`, right ??
For that you can use `str_replace()` function to replace `title` to `class`

Comment: @phpfresher: Yes you got me right. But the code should only execute when there is such kind of invalid HTML only. One more thing is there, to remove that additional title attribute containing null value from the first anchor tag. If you could post your code as an answer it would be great.

Comment: Ok sure.. i'll post it as answer...

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$original=array('<div title="comment_attach_image">','title=""');
$changedText=array('<div class="comment_attach_image">','');
str_replace($original,$changedText,$string);
```

It will replace the `title` with `class` and `title=""` with `NULL`...